# Better way to do this code

Tags: java, generics

A and AService are base classes.

B and BService extend these classes.

A and B are beans containing parameters for the services.

BService expects a B typed argument in the execute method.

```
public class A
{
    private int a1;

    public int getA1() { return a1; }
    public void setA1(int a1) { this.a1 = a1; }
}

public class B extends A
{
    private int b1;

    public int getB1() { return b1; }
    public void setB1(int b1) { this.b1 = b1; }
}

public abstract class AService
{
    public int execute(A a)
    {
        return a.getA1() + getValue();
    }

    public abstract int getValue(A a);
}

public class BService extends AService
{
    public int getValue(A a)
    {
        B b = (A) a;

        return b.getB1();
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this code ?
In particular, is there a way to avoid to cast objects ?

Comment: Where do you cast objects? What is your question? What did you try? What was the result?

Comment: abstract method does not specify body

Comment: @Balaswamy vaddeman : wrong copy/paste, edited.

Comment: @Tichodroma : There is only one cast in the code, in BService.The question is in the title, I just put it in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) are what you're looking for.  Typically, whenever you have a concrete class which can always safely cast a value, you can usually express this via generic parameters (and have it checked at compile time).

In this particular example, you'd declare the `AService` with a generic parameter which must be *some* subclass of A.  Then you use that parameter to make some methods specific to the particular type - in this case the `getValue` method, as something like

```
public class AService<T extends A> {

   // Now this takes a T - i.e. the type that a subclass is parameterised on
   public abstract int getValue(T a)

   // Execute will have to take a T as well to pass into getValue - an A
   // wouldn't work as it might not be the right type
   public int execute(T a)
   {
      return a.getA1() + getValue(a);
   }
}
```

where the `T` is a type parameter (conventionally a single uppercase letter).  Then you can declare the BService as

```
public class BService extends AService<B> {

   // The type is checked by the compiler; anyone trying to pass an instance
   // of A into this class would get a compile-time exception (not a class cast
   // at runtime)
   public int getValue(B b) {
       return b.getB1();
   }
}
```